# Why do I get the Run time error SIGSEGV in this code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++14

Today I was solving the problem on Codechef https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHPINTU here i get the Run time Error sigsegv below is the code please help me .Below is the C++ code

```cpp
    while(t!=0){
        int n,m;
        cin>>n>>m;
        int f[n],p[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>f[i];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>p[i];

        int freq[m+1];
        bool avail[m+1];
        memset(avail,false,sizeof(avail));
        memset(freq,-1,sizeof(freq));

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            freq[f[i]]+=p[i];
            avail[f[i]]=true;

        }
        int min = INT_MAX;
        for(int i=0;i<=m;i++){
            if(freq[i]<min && avail[i]==true){
                min=freq[i];
            }
        }
        cout<<min<<"\n";
        t--;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you creating an array with a size determined by user input?? At least check its value first!

Comment: You also access arrays by values you get from input. You should check values of f[i] too.

Answer (score 0):

```
cin>>n>>m;
int f[n],p[n];
```

**The length of array cannot be a variable.**
You can use `vector` or `new`.

```
vector<int> f(n);
//or
int *f = new int[n];
//remember to delete after new
```

other error found in your code:

```
memset(freq,-1,sizeof(freq));
freq[f[i]]+=p[i];
```

freq[i] is the total price of type i. Therefore, freq[i] is supposed to be initialized with 0 instead of -1.

And you can use `freq[i]==0` to determine if there are such baskets. It saves the memory occupied by `avail`.

Comment: Please consider suggesting `std::make_unique<int[]>()` rather than `new`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I can find in your code.
First, for all values of 'i' , f[i] can't be 0. So, freq[0] will have some garbage value and your are comparing it with 'min'. You can try subtracting 1 and then using it as the index in the freq array.

```
freq[f[i]-1]+=p[i];` avail[f[i]-1] = true;`
```

Also change the size of freq and avail to 'm' not 'm+1'. 
Second, initialize the freq array with 0 not -1, as you are adding values to its index so -1 as initial value will change the final results.

```
memset(freq,0,sizeof(freq));
```

I made a submission after making these changes, and it got accepted. You can try too.